# Unable to use chromedriver following OS upgrade

Tags: macos, permission, catalina, gatekeeper

> Error: “chromedriver” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

Updated OS is Catalina, version 10.15.2 (19C57).

chromedriver was working fine prior to the OS update. I've tried both the local chromedriver that was working previously as well as a newly downloaded copy.

What can I do to get this running again?

Answer (score 6):

Open system preferences, security and privacy, General tab and click "Open Anyway" or similar. It will ask for root password.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mh11784/10.15/mac/10.15

If that doesnt work, try the following, courtesy of [user365987](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/365987/kesara)

Open a terminal window and run this command to find the location of `chromedriver`:

```
which chromedriver
```

- Once you find the location, open that directory with MacOS Finder.
- `Ctrl` + `Click` the `chromdriver` file.
- Select **Open** on shortcut menu.
- Click **Open** on the dialog.

See [Open a Mac app from an unidentified developer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mh40616/mac)

Comment: No such option exists for me.

Comment: so does the duplicate help? Try to open the app first and then go to sys pref > security and privacy.